# Hover эффект кнопки python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, hover

У меня в цикле создаются 3 радиокнопки, вот код их создания:

```
curRad = []
for col in range(3):
    curRad.append(tk.Radiobutton(traffic, text=colors[col], variable=radVar,
                                 value=col, command=radCall))
    curRad[col].grid(column=col, row=1, sticky=tk.W)
```

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении курсора на радиокнопку она подсвечивалась, как на скриншоте ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399243/display-message-when-hovering-over-something-with-mouse-cursor-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.l1 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Hover over me")
        self.l1.pack(side="top")
        self.l1.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.l1.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

    def on_enter(self, event):
        self.l1.configure(background='red')

    def on_leave(self, enter):
        self.l1.configure(background="white")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true")
    root.mainloop()
```